# Flash Action Script 3 issue: image resize doesn't work

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, image, action

Check this link: http://inno_ebay.s3.amazonaws.com/xml-product-slide/index-2.html

This swf object load an external xml file (generated by php script which doesn't locate on the same machine) and then display the product list (thumbnail and title). The script was tested working fine on my local machine, but when updating to the hosting, the images don't resize. At the first i thought that it's hosting performance issue, so i migrated it to amazon s3, but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Comment: can you please post the image resize algorithm you are using?

Comment: If you are using the BitmapData.draw method then there a security restrictions when using an image loaded from another domain. Have a look at the documentation : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29

Comment: // fire when the thum image is loaded
  private function _thumbLoaded(e:Event):void{ 
     
   var tempLoader:Loader=Loader(e.target.loader);
   var _tf:TextField=TextField(tempLoader.parent.getChildByName("_loadingTf"));
   _tf.visible=false;
   if(tempLoader.content is Bitmap){
    //get the loaders content as a bitmap
    var _tempBM:Bitmap = Bitmap(tempLoader.content);
    _tempBM.smoothing=true;                                     
    _tempBM.width = 55;
    _tempBM.height = 55;
    Tweener.addTween(_tempBM, {_filter:glow, time:.5, transition:"easeoutsine"});       
   }
  
  }

Comment: This is the code: var _tempBM:Bitmap = Bitmap(tempLoader.content); _tempBM.smoothing=true; _tempBM.width = 55; _tempBM.height = 55; btw: i'm newbie in as3

Answer (score 1):

Your application throws a security access violation, which suggests that you are trying to load the image from a different domain to the one that the Flash resides on.  While that is possible using a [crossdomain.xml](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) file, you will run into trouble when you try to manipulate the remotely loaded images.

The workaround I generally use in these situations is to employ a proxy loader that exists in the same domain as the Flash movie.  This is a server script (PHP, ASP, whatever) that fetches the remote image for you.  Because Flash only talks to the proxy script, it believes that the image it is loading is from the local domain.  You will need to check with your hosting provider though, as many hosting companies prohibit the use of proxy scripts, even for benign purposes such as this.

Here's a simple example, although you would probably want to add a bit more security to a real world deployment:

proxyloader.php

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['path'])) {
        echo 'Error';
        exit;
    }
    $path = $_GET['path'];

    $fileContent = file_get_contents($path);
    if(substr($fileContent,0,6) == 'GIF89a' || substr($fileContent,0,6) == 'GIF87a') {
        $contentType = 'image/gif';
    } else if(substr($fileContent,1,3) == 'PNG') {
        $contentType = 'image/png';
    } else {
        $hexContents = bin2hex($fileContent);
        if(strtolower(substr($hexContents,0,4)) == 'ffd8') {
            $contentType = 'image/jpeg';
        } else {
            echo "Error";
            exit;
        }
    }

    header("Content-Description: Proxied Image File");
    header("Content-Type: $contentType");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$path);
    echo $fileContent;  
?>
```

and you would use this in a normal loader like this:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader()
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("proxyloader.php?path="+remoteFilePath);
loader.load(req);
```

Comment: This is probably the case. There is no crossdomain file loaded from i.ebayimg.com. An alternative approach to resize the image could be just to use `scaleX` and `scaleY`?

Comment: Without the cross domain file he may not be able to load the image at all, but if he can then scaling down without using Bitmap classes would be preferable to messing around with a proxy.

Comment: i'm newbie in as3. If there're no crossdomain.xml in domain i.ebayimg.com, the swf should not read any images right?

Answer (score 0):

**This is the XML:**

http://ebay.doufin.com/ebay_query/getItems.php?seller_id=lightupfoto&site_id=0&item_id=270738606484

**This is an item:**

```
<item link="http://cgi.ebay.com/2400w-Studio-Video-Red-Head-Continuous-Lighting-Kit-/270658608211" thumb="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/$(KGrHqZ,!lwE3JVj5IKsBODEto4sP!~~0_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007">
    <a href="http://cgi.ebay.com/2400w-Studio-Video-Red-Head-Continuous-Lighting-Kit-/270658608211" target='_blank'>2400w Studio Video Red Head Continuous Lighting Kit</a>
</item>
```

**This is the thumbnail:**

[image]

It's 400 x 400 px.

**So please, what is your question?**

Comment: `The script was tested working fine on my local machine, but when updating to the hosting, the images don't resize.` I guess his question is why don't they resize?

Comment: I did understand: Why they come in that big size. That would not be an AS3 question any more.

Comment: // fire when the thum image is loaded
  private function _thumbLoaded(e:Event):void{ 
     
   var tempLoader:Loader=Loader(e.target.loader);
   var _tf:TextField=TextField(tempLoader.parent.getChildByName("_loadingTf"));
   _tf.visible=false;
   if(tempLoader.content is Bitmap){
    //get the loaders content as a bitmap
    var _tempBM:Bitmap = Bitmap(tempLoader.content);
    _tempBM.smoothing=true;                                     
    _tempBM.width = 55;
    _tempBM.height = 55;
    Tweener.addTween(_tempBM, {_filter:glow, time:.5, transition:"easeoutsine"});       
   }
  
  }

Comment: the images are stored in ebay, i just read the image url address and load to flash, according to the code above, the image should be resized to 55px x 55px (_tempBM.width = 55; _tempBM.height = 55;), it does work in my local machine, but didn't work in hosting.

Comment: <code>// fire when the thum image is loaded private function _thumbLoaded(e:Event):void{ var tempLoader:Loader=Loader(e.target.loader); var _tf:TextField=TextField(tempLoader.parent.getChildByName("_loadingTf")); _tf.visible=false; if(tempLoader.content is Bitmap){ //get the loaders content as a bitmap var _tempBM:Bitmap = Bitmap(tempLoader.content); _tempBM.smoothing=true; _tempBM.width = 55; _tempBM.height = 55; Tweener.addTween(_tempBM, {_filter:glow, time:.5, transition:"easeoutsine"}); } }</code>